# Finding the minimal number of elements present in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ distinct real numbers, and $A_s$ the set of arithmetic means of two distinct numbers from $S$. For given $n \geq 2$ find the minimal number of elements in $A_s$.

I feel that it will probably happen when the set of elements in $S$ can be paired up in such a way that the sum of each pair is a constant, but I am unable to give a rigorous proof for it. Any help please?

Comment: Pairing them won't help, one needs minimum over all means of two elements from S, and a chosen pairing doesn't include all the means.

Comment: "can be paired up in such a way that the sum of each pair is a constant" Try it with a small set and see what happens.  There are $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ distinct pairs.  But it will be possible that multiple pairs have the same mean.  however it's not possible that *all* pairs have the same mean  ($a_c, a_b$ must have different mean than $a_c, a_d$.) Try it with say $n = 3,4,5$ and so if you get insight (and maybe a proof by induction).  Disclosure: I haven't tried to solve this.

Comment: Assume $a_1< a_2 <....$ Note if all are equal distance apart (i.e. in arithetic progression) so that $(a_1, a_n) = (a_2, a_{n-1}) =.... (a_i, a_{n-i})$.  Then you will have $(a_1,a_{n-1})$ will be a smaller mean and $(a_2, a_n)$ a larger.  You will have $2n - 1$ different means.  But can you prove this is the smallest number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the set $S = \{1,2,...,n\}$, has $A_S = \{\frac l2 : 3 \leq l \leq 2n-1\}$. I leave you to see this for yourself.

---

Now, let $n \geq 2$, and $S = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$ with $a_i < a_j$ for $i < j$. Clearly, $\frac{a_i + a_j}{2} < \frac{a_k + a_l}{2}$ for every $1 \leq i ,j,k,l \leq n$, with $\max\{i,j\} \leq \min\{k,l\}$ and at least two of $i,j,k,l$ distinct.

Denote $\frac{a_i + a_j}{2} = (i,j)$. Then $(1,2) < (2,3) < ... < (n-1,n)$ is an obvious chain, giving $n-1$ means. However, we can actually do better :
$$
(1,2) < (1,3) < (2,3) < (2,4) < (3,4) < (3,5) < (4,5) < \ldots < (n-2,n-1) < (n-2,n) < (n-1,n)
$$

are all members of $A_S$, where the inequality follows from what we said earlier. This shows that $|A_S| \geq 2n-3$ ($n-1$ elements from the earlier argument, and then one in between each gives $n-2$ more elements). Of course, we have found a set attaining equality.

---

For example, $\{1,2\}$ attains equality for the $n=2$ case. $\{1,2,3\}$ has three means and attains equality for the $n = 3$ case.

Comment: In your first statement, in which case will l come out to be 2?

Comment: Mistake. $l > 2$ must happen but $l = 3$ is possible.Note that the size of the set is $2n - 1 - 3  + 1 = 2n - 3$. Oh, I must edit the answer in that case. The answer is $\mathbf{2n-3}$, not $2n-1$.

Comment: I should have realized before posting ,that $2n-1$ is absurd for $n = 2$ : $A_S$ will always be a singleton in this case. However, the correction is now made.

Answer (score 1):

Let the elements be $a_1 < a_2 < .... < a_n$.

Now the $n-1$ means of $a_1$ and $a_i$ where $i \ne 1$ are all distinct as the $a_i$s are all distinct so there are at least $n-1$ distinct means.

Now the mean between $a_2$ and $a_i$ might be equal to one of the $a_1$ and $a_j$ means for a $j > i$.  But the $a_2, a_n$ must be larger than any mean we've done so far.  So that's at least one more distinct mean.

We can continue that the mean between each $a_k$ and $a_n$ must be larger than any mean betweeen $a_i, a_j$ where $i < k$.  So that means the means the $n-2$ means, $\frac{a_2 + a_n}2$ to $\frac {a_{n-1}+ a_n}2$ are each distinct and larger than the $n-1$ distinct means $\frac {a_1 + a-2}2$ to $\frac {a_1 + a_n}2$.

So at the very least there are $(n-1) + (n-2)=2n -3$ possible distinct means.

But is that possible to have that few?

And yes.  If the $a_i$ are in arithemetic progression (example if $a_i = i$) then the mean between $a_i$ and $a_j$ ($i <j$) will be the same as the mean between $a_{i-k}$ and $a_{j+k}$ for all $k; 0\le k < i$ and this is precisely such a case.

So the minimum is $2n -3$

....

A visual:  $a_1 < .... < a_n$ so

the means are

$\begin{cases} {\frac {a_1+a_2}2} & \frac {a_1 + a_3}2 &\frac {a_1 + a_4}2&...&\frac {a_1 + a_{n-2}}2&\frac {a_1 + a_{n-1}}2&\frac {a_1 + a_{n}}2 \\
=m_{1,2} & =m_{1,3} &m_{1,4}&...&=m_{1,n-2}&=m_{1,n-1}&=m_{1,n} \\
* & \frac {a_2 + a_3}2 &\frac {a_2 + a_4}2&...&\frac {a_2 + a_{n-2}}2&\frac {a_2 + a_{n-1}}2&\frac {a_2 + a_{n}}2\\
* & =m_{2,3} &=m_{2,4}&...&=m_{2,n-2}&=m_{2,n-1}&=m_{2,n}\\
* & * &\frac {a_3 + a_4}2&...&\frac {a_3 + a_{n-2}}2&\frac {a_3 + a_{n-1}}2&\frac {a_3 + a_{n}}2\\
* & * &=m_{3,4}&...&=m_{3,n-2}&=m_{3,n-1}&=m_{3,n}\\
...\\
* & * &*&...&\frac {a_{n-3} + a_{n-2}}2&\frac {a_{n-3} + a_{n-1}}2&\frac {a_{n-3} + a_{n}}2\\
* & * &*&...&=m_{n-3,n-2}&=m_{{n-3},n-1}&=m_{{n-3},n}\\
* & * &*&...&*&\frac {a_{n-2} + a_{n-1}}2&\frac {a_{n-2} + a_{n}}2\\
* & * &*&...&*&=m_{{n-2},n-1}&=m_{{n-2},n}\\
* & * &*&...&*&*&\frac {a_{n-1} + a_{n}}2\\
* & * &*&...&*&*&=m_{{n-1},n}\\
\end{cases}$

This makes at most $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ potentially distinct means.

Because $a_i > a_{i-1}$ we can see $m_{i,j} > m_{i-1, j}$ (every cell is larger than the cell to the left) and $m_{i,j} > m_{i,j-1}$ (every cell is larger than the cell above).

So $m_{1,2} < m_{1,3} < ... < m_{1,n} < m_{2,n} < .... < m_{n-1,n}$ make at least $2n -3$ distinct means.

By pigeon hole precision we can see that there can be exactly $2n -3$ distinct means if only if each $m_{j,k} = m{j+1, k-1}$.  I'll leave it to you to do the algebra to note that that occurs precisely if each $a_k = b + k*d$ for some $A$ and $d> 0$.  (i.e. if the $a_i$ are in an arithmetic progression.)

Hint.  $\frac {a_j + a_k}2 = \frac {a_{j+1} + a_{k-1}}2 \iff$

$a_{j+1} - a_j = a_k -a_{k-1}$.  Apply induction.

Comment: That step where you have argued that you have for every $a_k$ at least one mean greater than the mean calculated in the previous terms, shouldn't we be arriving at a minimum total of 2n-3, since at $a_2$ we have a minimum of n and continuing so on, upon arriving at $a_{n-1}$ shouldn't we be having 2n - 3 minimal number of means and considering $a_n$ will not affect the count?

Comment: Yes, you seem to be correct.  I had a dreaded "off by one" error.  Although i'm not sure what you mean "$a_n$ will not affect the count".  $(a_1,a_2).... (a_1, a_n)$ is $n-1$ terms.  And $(a_2,a_n)...(a_{n-1},a_n)$ are $n - 2$ more.  So $(n-1) + (n-2) = 2n -3$.

Comment: @I just mean to say that $a_n$ will not add one to our count just as all other $a_i$'s do for all the $i$'s in the range $2 \leq i \leq {n-1}$